# How can I edit the region of an aws lambda function already created?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have created a lambda function via the web console and when I try to setup the trigger S3 using my bucket I got this error:

[image]

Is obvious that I need to change the region because my bucket is on "us-west-2" and the function is on "us-east-1" but this is the thing:

In the creation process I did not see an option to select the region for the function and in edition mode I have checked all places searching an option to update the region but I could not find it.

What I am missing?

Comment: The region you have currently selected is displayed in the top of the web console. It is in the area above what you captured in the screenshot. You will need to delete the Lambda function, switch to the appropriate region, and then recreate it there.

Comment: So strange for AWS to force the user to rebuild the ruction in a new region versus just copying the code into the function.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Like Mark B said in comments. You need to select the region before to create the function.

On the AWS Lambda "admin home" page there is a dropdown
[image]